# How to prevent click on one of column in row - primeNG dataTables?

Tags: angular, font-awesome, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have table in primeNG:

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="cars" selectionMode="single"  
(onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
  <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
  <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
  <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
  <p-column styleClass="grid-col-btn" [style]="{'width':'58px'}">
    <ng-template let-gateway="rowData" pTemplate="body">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" 
(click)="deleteCarsFromList(car)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
     </button>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Because I use font awesome icon inside button the action after click doesn't work properly. When I click directly in icon I cannot trigger method (click), because action is from (onRowSelection). 
How can I prevent click on this specific column in table? To be sure that every time I use method added to button not whole table.

Comment: Are you saying that your `deleteCarsFromList(car)` method is not being called?

Comment: Is calling when I click on the border of button, but if I click directly in icon not calling

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see from your shared code, is that your `<ng-template>` is using `let-gateway` to assign your template variable, but you are using `car` inside your template.

[I have provided a plnkr that shows it working correctly](http://plnkr.co/edit/mqnfGTzeANrBR2S5eelY?p=info)

Comment: This was only example. 
But how to block the whole last column? So, when I clicked at this column the color of row will not change.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the row to NOT select when you click anywhere else in the column?

Comment: Yup. Because 'selectionMode="single"''works for each column. I want to prevent this click on the las column.

Comment: Looking at the source code for the component, I don't see any way you can do that, as is.  You'd probably have to edit the component.

Comment: If I have answered your question to your satisfaction, please mark it as the answer.